# If each DynamoDB item has unique schema, how can I query it?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DynamoDB to store my data. Each item has a name (primary key) and then unique attributes. How can I query by primary key, if the iOS DynamoDB sdk wants me to specify a model class (but each item is unique)? For example, I want to just input name (primary key), then the results will tell me what attributes that item has. Looking at aws's dynamodb sample for ios, you have to specify what these attributes are prior to the query, which I do not want to do. Is that the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples you were looking at are for the Dynamo Mapper which is just one of the abstractions you can use to work with Dynamo. In fact it is a pretty high level one and it is convenient if all items have a limited set of known attributes.

But underneath Dynamo is a document database that only requireas items to have a key (that may optionally be composed of a partition and a sort key) but other than that you can definitely store and query each item with a different set of attributes.

Please have a look at the DynamoDB low level API (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.LowLevelAPI.html) which supports querying items by key, and then iterating over each item's attributes. In fact, items are treated as a key-value map where the key is the attribute name and the value is whatever you want to store for each attribute.